# Using For Each Loop to Copy Conditional Formatting Color

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply the conditional formatting color of one cell to another cell. I am doing this in order to create a heat map. However, the values in the heatmap are not the values that fit the criteria of the conditional formatting (which is why I am copying the color from the cells that actually fit the criteria). I know I can do this process using a loop, but I am struggling in actually doing so.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range
    cnt = 2
    For Each cell In Range("J78:L81")
        Me.cell.Interior.Color = Me.Range("H" & cnt).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        cnt = cnt + 2
    Next cell

End Sub
```

The editor gives me a Compile Error saying "Method or data member not found" and it points towards the .cell in Me.cell.Interior.Color

Comment: It is probably because cell already has a meaning in VBA. Change that to targetcell or something and declare it.

Comment: The problem is the `Me` identifier before your declared `Range` "cell".

Comment: Just use `cell.Interior.Color=...`, you've already defined the range as being on the active sheet (implicitly).

Comment: Why is this code in a change event? Do you really want it run every time a selection is changed?

Comment: @SJR Do you have a recommendation on what it should be changed to?

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what you are doing, but you could attach it to a button or use the Change or SelectionChange event but restrict it to run only when a certain range of cells is changed rather than any cell at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Me` statement needs to be infront of the `Range("J78:L81")` instead of `Cell`.

```
For Each cell In Me.Range("J78:L81")
    cell.Interior.Color = Me.Range("H" & cnt).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```